# Comparing String with Community User's password

Tags: passwords, change-password

Scenario:
Custom community page includes custom Lightning Component with 3 text input fields:
- current password,
- new password,
- confirmed new password.

While I am able to validate 'new password' values if they are respecting Password Policies, I do not know how to validate firstly if value from 'current password' field is equal to currently logged in Community User's password. 
Is there any chance to check that?

Found this method : Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldPassword) but there are problems such as:
- it returns PageReference (so I do not even know what is the cause if this method fails),
- seems it doesn't work in Lightning Component scope, but only in VFP?